# XmlPullParserException when testing using Simple-Xml and Robolectric

Tags: android, testing, robolectric, xmlpullparser

I'm currently using Robolectric to write tests for Android. However when I try to unmarshall an XML document using simple-xml it throws

```
No valid parser classes found in      
org.kxml2.io.kXmlParser,org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer
```

After further inspection it looks like the exception occurs inside the PullProvider in the simple-xml framework at

```
XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
```

It looks like Robolectric doesn't support XmlPullParser. Has anyone found a workaround to this?

Comment: Search for how to write own shadow

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only work-around for this at the moment is to create your own shadow in Robolectric.

More information on creating shadows [here](http://robolectric.org/extending/)